# Heroku and Development behaving differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pg

I have an app that runs with my bug fixes correctly on my dev machine. I even stopped using sqlite3 and use pg in my local machine.

I deployed the app to a new heroku app as well still it behaves differently on production and development.

Here is how I push to heroku.

```
 >git commit all the files i have modified 
 > git push origin master
 > git push heroku master
```

The only other difference is that pg on local machine is 9.3.2 and pg on heroku seems to be 9.3.3
The same code behaves in differently. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  def pro_user

       @pro_user = Subscription.where(:email => current_user.email).pluck(:email) 
       rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound


  end
```

View Code is as follows  :

```
     <% if current_user %>

      <% if pro_user.empty? %>
        <!-- Not a premium user but logged in user so only free stuff -->              

     <% else %> 

        <!-- This is a  premium user so just display it all -->

     <% end %>   


 <% else %>
                   <!-- Not logged in-->
     <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you also share how they are different.

Comment: Yes basically in my app I have a free user and a premium user. When credit card is used to purchase, i convert the free user to pro user and unlock additional content in my views. This works perfectly in my dev machine for both sqlite3 and pg. But i have no clue why its not getting picked up by heroku.

Comment: Production console output. I don't know why the view is not updating in prod but does in dev. So basically in the rails console model/controller are giving the right output.
user1 is free user. user 2 is subscribed user.

   Subscription.where(:email =>'user1@gmail.com').pluck(:email)
=> []
   irb(main):005:0> Subscription.where(:email    =>'user2@gmail.com').pluck(:email)
=> ["user2@gmail.com"]

Comment: Can you provide the mechanism you used to set the "pro" information?

Comment: Rich, I use a coffee script. Basically if you see above console output comment, I see that my subscription table correctly holds the user's email if they purchase. See user1/user2 eg. above.  After hours of looking into this i think its the empty? method on the view. But i am still unsure. I will try nil? blank?

Comment: This is completely insane. I tried empty? nil?  blank? include?"@" nothing is working. While the same code works on my dev box.